When can bagging actually lead to higher variance?
Under the Gauss-Markov assumptions for linear regression, the ordinary least squares estimate (OLS) famously has the minimum variance amongst all unbiased linear estimators.
"Bagging" in this scenario is also linear and unbiased, and so its variance must be strictly worse. My intuition based on the case of zero independent variables (i.e. just a bias term) is that the variance approaches that of OLS as the number of models on randomly sampled data goes to infinity.
It does not surprise me that in the setting of decision trees, one obtains lower variance from bagging (random forests) than by using a single decision tree. But the explanations I've seen for this seem to prove too much, given what occurs for linear regression. What are some conditions that should be satisfied to ensure that bagging does not make the variance worse?

In a way, you can express a decision tree as a linear sum of indicator functions and it has a resemblance to linear regression. The fitting algorithms are however totally different because a sparse model is desired.

Nowhere does it say that Bagging must be "strictly worse", just not better than linear regression. "The goal is therefore to show that such an estimator has a variance no smaller than that of the OLS estimator"Gauss Markov Theorem.

@seanv507 are you claiming that bagging has the same variance here? I didn't work out a proof but I'm almost certain it's higher. Say we have n>>5 data points and each little model used in bagging uses a random subset of 5 data points. Let T be the number of little models we are averaging together. If T=1, the variance is obviously higher and as T approaches infinity, the variance approaches that of the linear regression model. I would be very surprised if the relationship between T and variance is not monotonically decreasing; in other words, bagging always has strictly higher variance

If the bags perform the same fitting, then with the linear regression the bagging doesn't create a different model space, as the average of linear models is the same linear model.
One should consider situations where the individual bagging models have some smaller model space, ie perform a different mor restricted fitting from the direct approach, but as a whole together, they create a large potential variation in the model space of the fitted function.
For example, we could consider linear regression with sparse models, where we keep only the most significant regressors. That might be a too simple model, but with bagging, we can average several simple models to end up with a complex function.
The r code below demonstrates this and shows how the bagging can also have a regularising effect in the case of linear regression.
set.seed(1)
n = 40

sim = function(){
  x = runif(n,0,2*pi)
  x1 = sin(x)
  x2 = sin(2*x)
  x3 = sin(4*x)
  x4 = sin(8*x)
  y = x1+x2+x3+x4 + rnorm(n,0,4)

  ### fit 1 model with 4 regressors
  b = lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4)$coefficients
  
  b2 = c(0,0,0,0,0)
  m = 10

  ### fit m times a model with 3 regressors
  for(i in 1:m) {
    sel = sample(1:n, replace = TRUE)
    mod1 = lm(y[sel]~x2[sel]+x3[sel]+x4[sel])
    mod2 = lm(y[sel]~x1[sel]+x3[sel]+x4[sel])
    mod3 = lm(y[sel]~x1[sel]+x2[sel]+x4[sel])
    mod4 = lm(y[sel]~x1[sel]+x2[sel]+x3[sel])
    best = which.min(c(
            summary(mod1)$r.squared,
        summary(mod2)$r.squared,
            summary(mod3)$r.squared,
        summary(mod4)$r.squared))
    if (best == 1) {
      b2[-2] = b2[-2] + mod1$coefficients/m
}
if (best == 2) {
  b2[-3] = b2[-3] + mod2$coefficients/m
}
if (best == 3) {
  b2[-4] = b2[-4] + mod3$coefficients/m
} 
if (best == 4) {
  b2[-5] = b2[-5] + mod4$coefficients/m
    }
  }

  return(c(b,b2))

}

### simulate coefficient errors several times
bs = replicate(300,sim())-c(0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1)

### compare the mean squared error

### without bagging 
# 0.4208891   0.8081512   1.0194485   0.9211920   0.9318923 
rowMeans(bs^2)[1:5]  

### with bagging
# 0.4450626 0.5599326 0.6097668 0.5491799 0.5852799 
rowMeans(bs^2)[6:10] 

This resembles the situation of averaging decision trees, it allows a function with many different nodes and variation. If you would fit a decision tree with the same number of nodes directly, then it would have too much variation.

A couple quick follow-ups while I try to understand this perspective:


If one picks a subset of independent variables randomly for each model, is there still an improvement of variance?


Is there bias here? I don't immediately see a "preference" amongst the coefficients introduced  (whereas L_p regressions "prefer" coefficients close to the origin"). But if we add in the assumption that the errors are i.i.d. and normal, OLS should have the minimum variance amongst all unbiased estimators.



Ah I see your point, we aren't estimating the coefficients here!

@TerenceC the linear regressions in the example are biased because we look for sparse solutions (one out of the four parameters is left out). However, by bagging them we end up with non-sparse solutions. The bagging is a way to increase the variance (but because it is done with biased low variance models, you end up with some regularisation). You make simple restricted models with little flexibility, and reintroduce the flexibility by fitting multiple times and averaging.

Just to make sure we're on the same page: normally when one talks about bias in the context of linear regression, they mean bias in the estimated coefficients. We're clearly not estimating coefficients here. So do you mean "biased" in the sense of the estimate of the model on a future input, viewing both the model and future output as random variables? (I can clarify that if that's unclear)

@TerenceC In the example I compared error in the coefficients (which are estimated with bias in the individual non-averaged models), but it could also be done for the values of the estimated/predicted conditional means.

bias is used here in the sense of Bias-Variance Tradeoff. the bias is specifically that (subsets of) coefficients are assumed to be zero (sparse)

In addition to Sextus' answer (+1).
I assume that we compare the variance of an ensemble estimator (e.g. bagging) against that of a well-calibrated "single" predictor trained on the full training set.
While in the context of generating predictions, bagging is known to reduce the variance, I see two main ways that can lead to higher variance in predictions:

We do improper aggregation. It is easy to try to get fancy about how we aggregate predictors; weighted averages based on a loss, using ranks, overfitting some hold-out set, etc. Simple averaging is robust to this, but strictly speaking a linear combination can still give suboptimal results.
We use highly correlated outputs. If our models' predictions are highly correlated and thus their errors are too, we might get higher variance without wanting it. This can particularly the case if our base predictors are badly underfitted. Bagging isn't magic, bad predictions are still bad predictions.

To be fair, I have seen these scenarios play out in the context of stacking estimators in ML competitions, but they are applicable to bagging estimators too, albeit in a lesser degree.
